# ASP.NET Azure publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-publishing

I deploy ASP.NET to Azure using VS 2012 publishing wizard. After success message in output window

Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped

Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped

the site starts in my google chrome tab, but I see only default Azure message 
"This website has been successfully created. There's nothing here yet...."

What is the problem?

Comment: are you publishing to AzureWebsites? have you checked if you are deploying to the right site?

Comment: I created a new Web Site in my Azure account, then I exported site publishing profile and imported it at Profile tab of Publish menu. Publish method has been set as Web Deploy. then I push Publish and VS output vindow said that everything is ok and opened browser with my site url: http://[sitename].azurewebsites.net. But there is no functional, only default Azure message "There's nothing here yet.."

Comment: Have you followed this tutorial exactly - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/26/deploying-windows-azure-website-using-visual-studio-web-publish-wizard.aspx

Comment: Can you check after you import your publishsettings file, all the details in the visual studio wizard are right?

Comment: Yes, your link was exactly that I use as an example. As I can see, everything is ok. Destinatoon URL is correct.

Comment: Can you try by going to a specific URL like `http://[sitename].azurewebsites.net/Controller/Action` and see if that works?

Comment: Yes, it works on a specific controller! Well, after it starts showing signs of life I can go further. Thanks a lot! You can post your recomendation of retry publishing and trying navigate to a specific controller, and I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publish your AzureWebSite and try to navigate to `http://[sitename].azurewebsites.net/Controller/Action`.

You got to set your `routeconfig.cs` correctly, so that when AzureWebSite opens up, it opens your default route.